# PHP file not copying correctly => file empty

Tags: php, file, directory

I'm currently trying to copy a file from location A to B in PHP. The file get's copied but it has 0 Bytes. I'm so confused why this file is empty after this process. This is my code:

```
if ( ! file_exists( $file_dir . $file_category ) ) {
    if ( ! mkdir( $file_dir . $file_category, 0777, true ) && ! is_dir( $file_dir . $file_category ) ) {
        throw new \RuntimeException( sprintf( 'Directory "%s" was not created', $file_dir . $file_category ) );
    }
    $data = '<html><body bgcolor="#FFFFFF"></body></html>';
    $file = fopen( $file_dir . $file_category . '/index.html', 'wb' );
    fwrite( $file, $data );
    fclose( $file );
    $data = 'deny from all';
    $file = fopen( $file_dir . $file_category . '/.htaccess', 'wb' );
    fwrite( $file, $data );
    fclose( $file );
}
copy( $output_dir . $filename, $file_dir . $file_category . '/' . $filename . '.pdf' );
```

Any help would be awesome.

Comment: Wouldn't things be easier if you assigned a variable from `$file_dir . $file_category`, so you wouldn't have to keep repeating that concatenation on every line?

Answer (score 0):

is it just me or do you have switched the source and the destination file in your copy line:

```
copy( $output_dir . $filename, $file_dir . $file_category . '/' . $filename . '.pdf' );
```

PHP docs says that the parameters is like this:

> copy ( string $source , string $dest [, resource $context ] ) : bool

but you first parameter uses "$output_dir" (might just be your variable name)

If this is not the case it would be helpful to know where you get "$filename" from since you are not validating it anywhere in your code, only "$file_category". Are you sure that your source file actually exists and has content?

Comment: `$file_dir . $file_category` is the directory he just created at the top of the code, so it probably is the destination.

Comment: @Barmar you are probably right. it just confused me that he uses "file_exists" to test if a folder exists. I would have written a comment but my rep did not allow it.

Comment: Yeah, he should use `is_dir()`

Comment: But despite the name, `file_exists()` will check for any kind of directory entry, not just files. There are separate functions like `is_file` and `is_dir` that check the type.

Comment: Yep. I just visited PHP docs again, and i must have forgotten that it could be used for folders as well. I have always used "is_dir" as long as i remember. Also to make sure i don't get a false positive if a file exists with the given name